# Lagrangean equations for the generating function of quadrangulations

Tags: co.combinatorics, singularity-theory, generating-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, analytic-functions

Let $M(z)$ be the generating function of edge-rooted connected quadrangulations, with $z$ marking the number of edges. I derived the following Lagrangean equations for $M(z)$:

$$M(z) = \psi(L(z)),~\psi(t) = \frac{1-4t}{(1-3t)^2}~,$$

$$L(z) = z \phi(L(z)),~\phi(t)=\left(\frac{t}{1-3t}\right)^{1/2}~.$$

Here is how I derived them. First note that, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of edge-rooted connected planar maps with $n$ edges and the set of edge-rooted connected quadrangulations with $2n$ edges. Also note that the Lagrangean equations for the generating function $m(z)$ of edge-rooted connected planar maps are:

$$m(z) = \Psi(l(z)),~\Psi(t) = t(2-t)/3~,$$

$$l(z) = z \Phi(l(z))~, \Phi(t) = 3(1+t)^2~,$$

where $z$ marks the number of edges. Tutte used the quadratic method to derive the above equations. What I did was to change the variable $z$ to $z^2$ in the intermediate step of the quadratic method. Then that gave rise to the Lagrangean equations for $M(z)$ described at the beginning.

My questions are:

1. The function $\phi(t)$ that I got doesn't seem to satisfy one of the conditions (page 402 (35) in [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)) for the singular inversion theorem (page 404 Theorem VI.6 in [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)). What is the reason for imposing that quoted condition in the book? Is there a more general version of the singular inversion theorem which doesn't require that condition?

**2. Is there another way to derive Lagrangean equations for quadrangulations?**

Please let me know if further clarification is needed. Thanks!